# Paypal vault for credit card storage

Tags: paypal

My company is looking to use the vaulting feature with Paypal for storing credit card info.  I am not on the development side of things.  I just need to know do we just need to have a paypal account to use this vault?  Do we need to have a business account or a contract with paypal in order to use this?  This is very time sensitive so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to set up a PayPal account for this functionality.

Those in charge of the financial account to which the PayPal account will be linked (i.e. your company's bank account) will also need to answer questions regarding the bank account's validity correctly in order to unlock full API access for your developer(s):
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

Your developers will also need to be set up, once the PayPal account has been confirmed and validated, with authorized logins for the account, as well, so they can test and ensure that PayPal transactions are confirmed during the development process.

A word of caution: Though I'm unaware of your business, its practices, etc. it's a hefty sum of responsibility and potential liability to offer the storing of user-sensitive financial information. If you're not prepared to handle the legal ramifications if this data is ever stolen or accessed without authorization, then this is not the development path your company should take.

Comment: Does it need to be a business paypal account?  We are just looking to store the CC information in their vault.  This is just a temp solution so we can meet a deadline.

Comment: Does it need to be a business paypal Pro account?  The one for $30 a month?

Comment: No, for the vault, which is part of the REST API, you don't need Pro.  Anything on REST is free with a business account.  I personally prefer Pro, though.  That system is just a lot more mature than the REST API at this point in time.  On Pro, the equivalent of the vault would be to use reference transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You would just need a business account to use REST API PayPal.List of [countries](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/) supported.

`The REST API supports many countries for PayPal account payments. All you need is to upgrade to a Business account. For country-specific offerings and limitations, refer to PayPal Offerings Worldwide and visit your country-specific site for further details.`

No need of a PRO account.